# Squared, what is in the post-scriptum?

Tags: mathematics, pattern, calculation-puzzle, geometry

Just received an invitation from a fellow mathematician for a party. The invitation is quite clear: where I need to be at what time is clearly said in the invitation, but at the bottom of the invitation he posted a P.S. as follows:

- Word 1 (2 letters): $[3*3]+[1*1]+[2*2]+[2*2]$
- Word 2 (5 letters): $((-[1*1] + [3*3] + [4*4] + [8*8] + [27*27]) \cdot [2*2] + [1*1] + [1*1] + [5*5] \cdot [27*27]) \cdot [2*2]$
- Word 3 (2 letters): $-[3*3]/2 + [9*9] + [15*15]$
- Word 4 (2 letters): $[3*3] + [1*1] + [2*2] + [2*2]$
- Word 5 (6 letters): $-[2*2] - [1*1] + [5*5] + [7*7] + [29*29] + [122*122] + [1791*1791]$

Not sure what he means, the only hint he gave me is as follows:

> [image]

Can you guys help me out finding what the P.S. says?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, judging from the hint, each $[m\ast n]$ means

> the total number of squares (of any size) to be found in an $m\times n$ square grid. The [formula for this](https://medium.com/@gootik/how-many-squares-are-there-in-an-n-x-m-grid-29e5e1a9d50) is $$\sum_{i=0}^{\min(m,n)-1}(m-i)(n-i).$$

In our case, we seem to have only $[n\ast n]$, in which case

> the formula is simply $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

So rewriting all the expressions we've been given:

- Word 1 (2 letters): $[3*3]+[1*1]+[2*2]+[2*2]$

  > $=(14)+(1)+(5)+(5)=25$
- Word 2 (5 letters): $((-[1*1] + [3*3] + [4*4] + [8*8] + [27*27]) \cdot [2*2] + [1*1] + [1*1] + [5*5] \cdot [27*27]) \cdot [2*2]$

  > $=((-(1)+(14)+(30)+(204)+(6930))\cdot(5)+(1)+(1)+(55)\cdot(6930))\cdot(5)=(7177\cdot5+2+381150)\cdot5=2085185$
- Word 3 (2 letters): $-[3*3]/2 + [9*9] + [15*15]$

  > $=-(14)/2+(285)+(1240)=1518$
- Word 4 (2 letters): $[3*3] + [1*1] + [2*2] + [2*2]$

  > $=(14)+(1)+(5)+(5)=25$, same as Word 1.
- Word 5 (6 letters): $-[2*2] - [1*1] + [5*5] + [7*7] + [29*29] + [122*122] + [1792*1792]$

  Here there is a mistake, as it should actually be $1791$. (We'll see why later.)

  > $=-(5)-(1)+(55)+(140)+(8555)+(612745)+(1916589696)=1917211185$

So the overall solution is

> $25,2085185,1518,25,1917211185$. Breaking each number up into chunks that represent letters, we get $[2,5],[20,8,5,18,5],[15,18],[2,5],[19,17,21,1,18,5]$

giving

> BE THERE OR BE SQUARE

which certainly fits the theme of the puzzle!

---

I'm guessing this is one of those puzzles that took much longer to create than to solve :-)

Comment: You're faster. Go for it.

Comment: If you haven't already checked, changing it to 1791 produces the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is most likely

> **BE THERE OR BE SQUARE**

Because

> Using deduction based on the first word, the total of which is 25, 2 letters being 2, 5 or **BE**
>  Also, the same sequence is used for the 4th word.
>  So,
>  **BE**
>  (5 letters)
>  (2 letters)
>  **BE**
>  (6 letters)
>  The title sold it for me, has to be SQUARE
>  This is my complete answer/explanation. All math was done completely and faster by Rand al'Thor and would be very redundant and unneeded if I did it as well. :) Plus, I'm at work and my boss gave me other tasks to do.

Comment: You beat me to it because I did all the calculation before posting :-) +1 anyway, I'm still hunting for a mistake I must have made somewhere ...

Comment: I did the first one and went, Oh, okay... Sounds like this. :) EDIT: I didn't really want to do all of the necessary math, though. So, yea! Nice work.